# Is it possible to "convert" a markov chain into a neural network's initial state, to "seed" it?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, neural-network, markov-chains

E.g. neural networks take a while to "start up", and with big enough datasets, that could be weeks or months of wasted time, and my idea is to provide a better starting point, that is closer to coherence, based on a simple markov-chain-based model to reduce said amount of time.

I tried googling around, but didn't find anything, although I've once seen a video of someone having written an algorithm to convert cellular automata rules into an ANN, which suggests that it's possible to transform other models into neural networks, but I'm afraid that doing such a thing is beyond me.

Does anyone have any idea, or possibly some resources, on doing such a transformation?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @matcheek Ah... is it possible to move a question, or do I have to ask it again over there?

Comment: Moving question to different forum would require mod powers that I don't have but can't see anything wrong with asking the same question on stats.